# How Is the MATLAB `filter()` Function So Fast?

Tags: matlab, infinite-impulse-response, finite-impulse-response, software-implementation

How is the [`filter()`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/filter.html) implemented in MATLAB? How is it so fast?
What's the fastest implementation of a FIR filter?

Comment: You may look on the code of `Octave` and `Scipy`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually it seems MATLAB implementation of the `filter()` function is pretty straight forward and not fast.

For a fast implementation, have a look at [FilterM](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/32261) by Jan Simon.

### Update

In the latest releases of MATLAB (From R2016b and above) the performance of the `filter()` function has improved.
The methods to accelerate those operations are usually based on:

1. Utilizing Vectorized  / SIMD Operations (SSE / AVX in `x86`).
2. Multi Threading.
3. Loop Unrolling.

Update (2021):
In recent MATLAB versions the function was accelerated using parallelization and vectorization.

Comment: MATLAB uses a time domain Direct Form II Transposed Canonical structure to realize its filter() or conv() functions. It's not specifically designed to be fast. An FFT based implementation would be faster or fastest when data lengths are suitable...

Comment: Actually `fft()` based will be faster only in the cases dimensions are really perfect for it which doesn't happen often in my experience. Filtration both with `fft()` or directly on data are usually memory bounded and the `fft()` approach stresses memory more.

Comment: By the way, MATLAB's `conv()` is much faster than `filter()` in the cases of *FIR* filters.

Comment: I don't know your MATLAB version but in my(old) version its help says 
`The conv function is an M-file that uses the filter primitive.`... So I don't how how it could be faster ? May be newer versions use other approaches ?

Comment: And about fft() version, yes the length should be suitable for fastest performance, otherwise you will not get the benefit...

Comment: In MATLAB R2016a and above `conv()` which calls `conv2()` is implemented in `C`. It uses Multi Threading and SIMD. It is very hard to beat it with `fft()`.

Comment: Yes SIMD through SSE and AVX will definetely help but they also use parallelization for fft() too, and I remember in my code base from matlab 2017 where fft2() outperforms conv2() by orders of magnitude when data and kernel lengths are large enough.

Comment: Well, modern images are having thousands of pixels in each dimension. Real world kernels are no larger than ~25-30 pixels in the widest dimensions. Hence in practice it is always faster to use the direct methods. At least in my experience. Maybe someone will open a question about this and we'll do some simple testing.

Answer (score -1):

filter() implements an IIR-filter. You mention FIR filter. While IIR is a generalization of FIR, it makes some sense to think of them as two different things wrgt optimization.

Generally, MATLAB may use libraries or point optimizations implemented in FORTRAN, C or Assembly using algorithmic optimizations, as well as SIMD, multi threading or any other clever trick that makes the function faster while still deemed sufficiently general and accurate